Docker Symfony Monolog can't write logs to stderr or stdout, error.log and access.log were empty
I have a project running Symfony 6.2, applied Monolog for logging errors. I used default configuration of Monolog to write debug messages to php://stderr. Everything seems to work fine but error.log or access.log of Ngnix were empty. Here are my monolog config:
monolog:
    channels:
        - deprecation
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
            buffer_size: 50 
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: php://stderr
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.json
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
        deprecation:
            type: stream
            channels: [deprecation]
            path: php://stderr

when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: php://stderr
                level: debug
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
            deprecation:
                type: stream
                channels: [deprecation]
                path: php://stderr

Is there any ideas?

This is not a Symfony problem. I guess that you still need to do something about the PHP-FPM configuration. How to configure PHP logs for Docker / How to get php-fpm to log to stdout / stderr when running in a docker container

@Bademeister I've read many articles and my configurration is similar to 2 articles you mentioned. Unfortunately, no good result found.
